# How to get Resized/Thumbnail Image : UWP

Tags: image, thumbnails, win-universal-app

Currently I was working on a UWP application. I captured the ink strokes into an image. Now the same image need to display as a preview. So the original image need to re-size to shorter size or thumbnail need to be generated.

I tried with using the larger image directly as a source to shorter sized image canvas --> not working (visible image quality degrade)

I also used Transcode of image programatically --> same result as above

I test with the same image. Re-sized the same image using paint, and there interestingly the quality of the re-sized image remains good.

Please help me to solve the issue I faced.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure, need to see some code, but could be how you are saving the image? Here an example:

```
try
{
    Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker save = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
    save.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    save.DefaultFileExtension = “.png”;
    save.FileTypeChoices.Add(“PNG”, new string[] { “.png” });
    StorageFile filesave = await save.PickSaveFileAsync();

    using (IOutputStream fileStream = await filesave.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
        {
            await m_InkManager.SaveAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
    dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

I will post a great tutorial of Can Bilgin that explain perfectly all about inking.

[Drawing / Inking API in WinRT (C#) – I](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/drawing-inking-api-in-winrt-c-i/)

[Drawing / Inking API in WinRT (C#) – II](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/drawing-inking-api-in-winrt-c-ii/)

[Drawing / Inking API in WinRT (C#) – III](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/drawing-inking-api-in-winrt-c-iii/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
May be you are using win2d.uwp nuget package. I somehow able to fix this issue to some extent and it is looking the best possible solution till now. Here is my thread on msdn
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d456e23-54a0-4a36-80d2-e2348a8702a1/uwphow-to-get-resizedthumbnail-image-uwp?forum=wpdevelop